# Container 100% and expanding

Tags: html, css, height

I have a page structure similar to this:
**CSS**:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
#pagina{
    height: 100%;
}
#list{
    height: 100%;
}
.persona{
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 40%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id=pagina>
<div id=list>
    <div class="persona">Prova</div>
    <div class="persona">Prova</div>
    <div class="persona">Prova</div>
</div>
```

I would like the page has a height of 100% and it is adapting to its content.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

make your container div height:auto and min-height:100%. That will allow your
content area to fill 100% of the viewport for standardized css browser

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/aFzw5/

I've made some changes to your code that allows your content to fill 100% of the page.  I also added in some large colored borders so you can easily see each container.  Once you remove the borders - the containers will fill the page 100%;

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
        html{
            height:100%;
            border:10px solid red;
        }
        body{
            height:100%;
            border:10px solid yellow;
        }
        #pagina{
            height: 100%;
            border:5px solid black;
        }
        #list{
            height:100%;
            border:5px solid green;
        }
        .persona{
            border:5px solid blue;
            height: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagina">
        <div id="list">
            <div class="persona">Prova</div>
            <div class="persona">Prova</div>
            <div class="persona">Prova</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would like the body adapts to the page content (the property of class "persona" is that the height is 40%).

Comment: the red line remains at 100% of the page

Comment: You can't have 3 containers that are 40% of the page height, the containers will overflow to 120% (40 x 3 = 120)

Comment: You can either change your persona height to 33.3% to get close to filling the 100% of the page height, or you can adjust your total height to 120%.  If you intend to keep a border around the entire page, you have to account for that in your calculations as well, otherwise the div's will overflow the space you allow.

Comment: The problem is that I have a dynamic list of people. I don't solve putting height: 33.3%.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I understand you correctly.  You want the outer container to be a minimum of 100% of the screen, but could extend over, and then the "persona" divs would be a fixed height allowed to overflow the outer container?

Comment: The outer div should have height:auto and height in div 40%.